# Basic AngularJS service request

Tags: javascript, angularjs, api, service

I am trying to make changes to a very basic sample app so to decouple the static portion of the application from the server side based on Springboot. I want to run the AngularJS static portion of the app on nginx and make remote service calls to the Springboot application.

Here is gist of the application ...

```
angular.module('blah', ['ent1', 'errors', 'status', 'info', 'ngRoute', 'ui.directives']).
config(function ($locationProvider, $routeProvider) {

    $routeProvider.when('/errors', {
        controller: 'ErrorsController',
        templateUrl: 'assets/templates/errors.html'
    });
    $routeProvider.otherwise({
        controller: 'MyController',
        templateUrl: 'assets/templates/albums.html'
    });
}
);

function MyController($scope, $modal, $location, $http, a, b, st) {


$scope.init = function() {
    console.log($location.host());  
--->        $location.host("http://somewhereelse:8080/");
    console.log($location.host());
    ....
};
}
```

Some details have been removed for readability sake.

As you can see, I have injected `$location` into my controller, which I assume is where I would change the host. However, the before and after console.log still show me "localhost".

How do I make a remote API call to a service using AngularJS? Like I said, it is probably a very basic question.

Answer (score 0):

Hope you are trying to make some API calls from your angular application. For that you can use angular $http service.

A sample code will look like this:

```
    // Simple GET request example:
$http({
  method: 'GET',
  url: '/someUrl'
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
    // this callback will be called asynchronously
    // when the response is available
  }, function errorCallback(response) {
    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
    // or server returns response with an error status.
  });
```

For More details see the official doc:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http